# How do I use a previous program that I've written in a new program that I am currently writing?

Tags: python-3.x, module

I have written a small program and saved it as a module using `if __name__ == '__main__:' main()`

Now I want to use this program in another program that I'm writing.
How do I do that without just copying and pasting the previous program's code?
I have tried import `filename.py` but that doesn't work.

Some context: The first program calculates the area of a polygon;
The second program needs to use the area in order to calculate the centroid of a polygon.

Comment: Almost every `.py` file can be used as a module. What you need is to wrap the code to functions or classed so that you were able to call say `filename.func(x)`. The condition `__name__ == '__main__'` holds only when the `filename.py` is used as a script, not as a module. It does not say whether the `.py` file can or cannot be used as a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the .py. It's just `import filename`.